# How to add es2020 features to existing react app?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-2020

I want to use the new features of es2020 in my react app.
Tried to install `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2020` and added `.babelrc` file with

```
{
  "presets": ["es2020"]
}
```

However it still doesn't work.
How to set up the new features of es2020 with a react app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change in the `tsconfig.json` file the target to `"target": "ES2019"`

Answer (score 1):

The latest [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) supports `es2020` out of the box, and it has a `Typescript` template too. Their `.tsconfig` is set to output `es5`, but allows code to be written with the latest ES features:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ]

  // ...

  }
}
```

Comment: I had to transfer m existing react app